# Job search in another country?

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom, relocation

So, because my partner has been offered an excellent position abroad and I would like to join them there, I am about to start a job hunt in another country. Unlike my partner, who was living there at the time of their search, I am still living in my birth nation.

Other than the need to constantly request Skype interviews or similar (I can't fly for every interview), what obstacles can I expect in such a job search?

*Relocation would be from the East-Netherlands, to South-West England*

Comment: I can't see any obstacles.  It's only a time zone away, almost the same culture; since you are from Holland naturally you speak English better than 99% of English-speakers.  If a company hires someone from say the North of England, or you, there is little difference in the costs involved.  Good luck!

Comment: If your partner will be moving there before you can follow you will have an excellent home base, which might make getting on-site interviews with reimbursement easier, as they only have to pay the flight, not the accommodation.

Comment: @skymningen it's not a matter of cost, it's a matter of time. Flying back and forth and still be fresh for an interview is going to take two days at least. And as I am still currently in a job, that time just isn't there.

Comment: A job search will cost you much more time than that. And for local interviews, you would also have to go during work hours, drive or travel by train, and that would add up quickly. Try having more than one interview over the course of two or three days. By the way, going there will also give you time to spend with your partner. Two important things covered.

Comment: exactly, as @skymningen says there is little difference.  In the USA, this would be like looking for a job 1 or 2 states away.  Again, naturally Weckar speaks English better than all of us English-speakers, so that's no problem.

Comment: From my experience (within different countries in the UE: scientific/tech companies) you'll typically have a Skype interview. If everything goes well they'll invite you to spend a day with them (the company will pay any costs involved). If everything goes well you'll be offered a job. If you get to step 2 you'll know your chances are pretty good so you'll probably won't have to make too many of those "visit" days (unless you keep refusing offers).

Answer (score 3):

You just look for jobs, write CVs, contact agencies, just like anyone else in the UK would do. Good written English always helps.

At the moment you can move to the UK without any problems. Nobody knows how that will change when the UK leaves the EU, nobody including the UK government, which seems to be particularly clueless. To my best knowledge, you should be able to stay until two years after the UK leaves the EU, that is March 2021. This may change when Theresa May loses her job, or when she gets sufficiently told off by the EU, which are each quite likely.

Comment: We should be able to apply for resident status before then.

Comment: For the second paragraph in general +1

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the industry you work in, it may or may not be common practice for companies (especially larger ones) to have a well-defined recruiting process for candidates living in other countries. This typically involves a few phone or Skype interviews followed by an on-site interview or day of interviews.

There isn't really a difference in how you approach this - just apply as you normally would and be open about your situation when it comes up (don't "request a Skype interview", just say you currently live in the Netherlands and roughly when you plan to move to the UK - the implication there is clear).

If you don't require work sponsorship (i.e. a work permit), it's important to mention that to potential employers, as you can still work for companies that don't provide that (for your specific scenario, it's probably less important to mention, as employers would likely know this already, but there isn't much harm in casually mentioning it anyway).

Alternatively, you can consider arranging let's say a month-long trip to the UK at your own expense (depending on how much leave you have and/or can afford and when you're actually moving). Then contact recruiters or apply for jobs directly with the intention of having the interviews take place during your stay there. I haven't personally done this, but I know people who this has worked for. In theory, some employers may not want to fly you over despite being eager to interview you.

Comment: Especially true when companies look for more senior roles that are not a dime a dozen per se.

Answer (score 1):

As for the Netherlands, most of the CEO's here are always excited to talk to you and help you if you have something of value to offer.

I would suggest going to [angelist](http://www.angelist.co), this is a website for startups with a lot of them located in the Netherlands. This is where my Italian colleague found his job here as well. My CEO helped him to make sure he could travel here as well as some other things that made his relocation go without problems.

Comment: You may have misread: I'm moving AWAY from the Netherlands.

Comment: Ah, apologies..

Comment: @WeckarE. While Idris misread, the site they suggested seems on a first look seems to country-independent, that is you can try see what comes up as based in the UK there.